# run css animation with javascript on specific action

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Im trying to add a class for an autogrow animation effect to a textarea element.

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/d0kmg7d3/15/

```
var tx = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for (var i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
  tx[i].setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (tx[i].scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
  tx[i].addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);
}

function OnInput(e) {
  this.style.height = 'auto';
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';


}
```

how can I toggle the animation only when the height is triggered?
something along this line:

```
this.classList.toggle("horizTranslate")
```

but how do I detect when the height is changed?

Comment: What do you mean by the height is triggered? Do you mean whenthe text area's text exceed the box height?

Comment: so in that demo, the textarea increases when new text is added. I'm trying to add an animation/class to that moment so the textbox doesn't jump but it smoothly changes the height. Does that make sense?.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you don't need, JS to do this, with pure css you can do it, the only with you need to care about `transition` and `max-height` css attributes.

I just modified your code in the example, I hope I can help you.

See the code below.

```js
var tx = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
/*for (var i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
  tx[i].setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (tx[i].scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
  tx[i].addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);
}*/

function OnInput(e) {
  this.style.height = 'auto';
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
 
  
}
```

```css
textarea {
  max-height: 40px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 1em;
}

textarea:focus {
  background: orange;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="horizTranslate" placeholder="Type, paste, cut text here..."></textarea>
```

Comment: hi, yeah I knew how to add a transition like that. The problem is I'm not able to add the same animation when the actual height is resized at the moment more characters are added. do you know what I mean? that's why I was thinking ar a JS toggle function.